# How to set different values of the elements of a np.arrays to different values in Python 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-2.7, numpy-ndarray

Let I have the following np.array:

```
>>>a=np.array([20, 10,5,10,5,10])
>>>array([20, 10,  5, 10,  5, 10])
```

Now, I want to replace 20 and 10 by 1 and 5 by 0.

Is there a function that can do that in one step?

Here is what I have tried:

```
>>>a[a==10]=1
>>>a[a==10]=1
>>>a[a==5]=0
```

and I am getting my desired output, which is:

```
>>>array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

As you can see, I had to follow three steps in order to get my result. But I want to get my result only in one step. Is there a function that can deliver my result in one step?

** Edit: As suggested by Salvatore, I tried the following: **

```
import pandas as pd
>>>a=np.array([[20, 5, 10, 5, 10, 7, 5]])
>>>a = pd.Series(a).replace([20,10,7,5],[1,1,1,0]).values
```

But with the above method I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Comment: If you want to replace 5 with 0, why are you replacing 5 with 1 first??  You could use something like `np.select`, but you still have to create the 3 separate masks, so it wouldn't get you a real performance gain, but would help if you have overlapping conditions.

Comment: @user3483203 ;   I made a mistake while writing the code. I don't want to replace 5 with 1. I want to replace 20, and 10 with 1 and 5 with 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the map function.

```
list(map(lambda x: int(x in [10,20]),a))
```

The map function will apply the function in the first argument to all the elements in the list given as the second argument.
Here the  lambda function returns 0 if the element is not 10 or 20, and 1 if the element is 10 or 20.

EDIT FOLLOWING THE AUTHOR'S COMMENT

To keep the result as a numpy array, you can use the from iter numpy function :

```
a = np.fromiter(map(lambda x: int(x in [10,20]),a),dtype=int)
```

Comment: @robinhood ; But the solution that you gave me would turn my np.array into a list, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it does. Let me edit it to keep a numpy array.

Answer (score 2):

Despite @robinood's answer works fine, I'd prefer this way:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.Series(a).replace([20,10,5],[1,1,0]).values
```

This because, for long arrays, cycling can take a great amount of time. For this reason i tested both mine and @robinood's solution on `a = np.random.choice([20, 10, 5], size=10_000_000)` and the results are the following:

- my solution: `655 ms ± 7.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`
- @robinood's solution `9.51 s ± 25.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: Your solution is not working for me. It gives me the following error: ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional

Comment: @shashankranjan are u sure you have a 1-dimensional array?

Comment: in your edit `a` has shape (1,7) so it is not 1-dimensional. Please `ravel()` your array before convert it in a series (`a=np.array([[20, 5, 10, 5, 10, 7, 5]]).ravel()`)

Comment: I am getting my array from the multiplication of a row array by a matrix. For example, >> a= np.array([[1,0,1], [0,1,1],[1,0,1]]), >>b=np.ones((1,3),dtype=int), >> a=np.dot(b,a), the output as the result of multiplication I am getting is >>array([[2, 1, 3]]). So, you can see, even though my output array has only one row, but it is not one-dimentional. What can I do to convert it into one dimensional?

Comment: @shashankranjan so you have to `a=np.dot(b,a).ravel()`